# jQuery Conflicting with jquery in wordpress

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have built the homepage to a website and my category slider was working fine, once I have built the site in wordpress and added a layered slider plugin my category slider has stopped working..

Here is the website http://www.fiestapaints.co.uk/new/

I think it is a conflict between these 2 pieces of jquery, but I can't change the layer slider one (first jquery code) as it's quite a complicated plugin..

If someone could help me with this that would be great, thank you in advance

```
<script pagespeed_orig_type="text/javascript" type="text/psajs" orig_index="9">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery("#layerslider_1").layerSlider({
          width: '940px',
          height: '395px',
          responsive: false,
          responsiveUnder: 0,
          sublayerContainer: 0,
          autoStart: true,
          pauseOnHover: false,
          firstLayer: 1,
          animateFirstLayer: false,
          randomSlideshow: false,
          twoWaySlideshow: true,
          loops: 0,
          forceLoopNum: true,
          autoPlayVideos: true,
          autoPauseSlideshow: 'auto',
          youtubePreview: 'maxresdefault.jpg',
          keybNav: true,
          touchNav: true,
          skin: 'minimal',
          skinsPath: 'http://www.fiestapaints.co.uk/new/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/skins/',
          globalBGColor: 'transparent',
          navPrevNext: true,
          navStartStop: true,
          navButtons: true,
          hoverPrevNext: true,
          hoverBottomNav: false,
          thumbnailNavigation: 'hover',
          tnWidth: 100,
          tnHeight: 60,
          tnContainerWidth: '60%',
          tnActiveOpacity: 35,
          tnInactiveOpacity: 100,
          imgPreload: true,
          yourLogo: false,
          yourLogoStyle: 'left: 10px; top: 10px;',
          yourLogoLink: false,
          yourLogoTarget: '_self',
          cbInit: function (element) {},
          cbStart: function (data) {},
          cbStop: function (data) {},
          cbPause: function (data) {},
          cbAnimStart: function (data) {},
          cbAnimStop: function (data) {},
          cbPrev: function (data) {},
          cbNext: function (data) {}
      });
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script pagespeed_orig_type="text/javascript" type="text/psajs" orig_index="3">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('#mycarousel').
      jcarousel({
          auto: 2,
          wrap: 'last',
          initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
      });
  });

  function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
      carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function () {
          carousel.startAuto(0);
      });
      carousel.buttonPrev.
      bind('click', function () {
          carousel.startAuto(0);
      });
      carousel.clip.hover(function () {
              carousel.stopAuto();
          },
          function () {
              carousel.startAuto();
          });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Also, please fix the formatting of your question, so that it's easier to read.

Comment: you know you are loading jquery 1.8.3 and jQuery 1.10.1

Comment: It is the product categories that isnt working, if you look towards the bottom they are all displayed when they should be in a line with the left and right arrow top right, clicking that makes them slide.. see this examle for the product slider at the bottom http://thisiscommon-designpreview.co.uk/fiesta-paints/index.html

Comment: it shouldn't be loading 2 jqery's, I've checked the header.php fileand I only have one link to the latest file

Answer (score 0):

pagespeed type=text/psajs  pagespeed will defer these javascripts by creating an onload event.  However, onload fires AFTER document.ready...

So the order of operation for your code is...

document.ready fires

onload fires running your scripts hooking to document.ready

document ready has already fired, so calls to ready will be executed immediately

so during onload

1. layerslider function is called
2. jcarousel function is called, which attempts to point to a callback that isn't defined
3. initcallback is defined

You need to define initcallback and any other callback or service functions during the onload before you call jquery ready jcarousel

```
<script pagespeed_orig_type="text/javascript" type="text/psajs" orig_index="3">
  function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function () {
      carousel.startAuto(0);
    });
    carousel.buttonPrev.
    bind('click', function () {
      carousel.startAuto(0);
    });
    carousel.clip.hover(function () {
          carousel.stopAuto();
    },
    function () {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
  };

  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').
    jcarousel({
      auto: 2,
      wrap: 'last',
      initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
  });

</script>
```

Also, the jquery ready is completely superfluous within the context of this code.  You can remove it and just make the calls.